# how to fix asp button postback in downloaded theme

Tags: asp.net

when i use a downloaded theme i.e from *w3layouts.com* and modify the html controls to asp controls the asp button doesn't work i.e it doesn't go to its "**on_click**" event .
when i use

the control goes to its backend **onclick** event but it doesn't get the text box values

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" UseSubmitBehavior="false" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Check the js files.I think they might have disabled the submit button.
Try to comment it.This is what i came across in my downloaded theme.This code prevents form from postback.

```
jQuery('form').submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
```